# Adding more than one element at a time to a list generated with a loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to make a list like this:

```
[str(s),'Numpad{}'.format(s) for s in range(0,10)]
```

that produces:

```
['1' , 'Numpad1' , '2' , ... ]
```

Is there a syntactically allowable way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to do exactly? Maybe there is a better approach to your goal?

Comment: Python3 returns Invalid format...

Comment: I want to use the list in a conditional statement.

Comment: Please show your *expected* output, then optionally add *how* you want to use this

Comment: The expected output is in the question.

Comment: Look at the duplicate I flagged. The first solution does what you want. Replace each lambda with what you are trying to do in your comprehension. So first lambda does a `str(s)`, second lambda does a `"Numpad{}".format(s)`

Comment: It can't be done in a single line?

Comment: @AlexEshoo Why does it have to be a single line? Why is that important?

Comment: I was just curious

Answer (score 1):

I found a great solution to you question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) on a question regarding flatting of lists.

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(*[[str(s),'Numpad{}'.format(s)] for s in range(1,10)]))
```

Here more elegant solution provided by tdelaney in the comments section:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([str(s),'Numpad{}'.format‌​(s)] for s in range(0,10)))
```

Comment: You can slim that down a bit: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([str(s),'Numpad{}'.format(s)] for s in range(0,10)))`

Comment: nit: range(1, 11). Even though OP has range(0, 10), their output is starting at 1.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney! Thanks @idjaw! Fixed!

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Made a mistake on my part. range(1, 11) to actually make it end at 10. :)

Comment: The asker never mentioned, whether it should end with 9 or 10 :)

Comment: @tommy.carstensen good point :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a tuple?

```
In [1]: [(str(s),'Numpad{}'.format(s)) for s in range(0,10)]
Out[1]:
[('0', 'Numpad0'),
 ('1', 'Numpad1'),
 ('2', 'Numpad2'),
 ('3', 'Numpad3'),
 ('4', 'Numpad4'),
 ('5', 'Numpad5'),
 ('6', 'Numpad6'),
 ('7', 'Numpad7'),
 ('8', 'Numpad8'),
 ('9', 'Numpad9')]
```

Iterate over that with

```
for (val, numpad) in lst:
```

Comment: Not really what I want since I don't want to search for tuples

Comment: Well, you didn't say anything about searching

Comment: @AlexEshoo I think you should provide more information in your question on what you are trying to achieve so readers can know how to give you a good solution with *all* the necessary information.